# How to change automatically html <input> tags using python?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, input, user-input

**Problem.**
I have a real html page, which could be parsed by beautifulsoup (or something else) if needed.
I have some identical input tags on this page. Say, a 1000 input tags that look like:

```
<input class=​"text_class​" type=​"text" size=​"3" value=​"20">​
```

And on the end of the page I have submit-type input tag that looks like this:

```
<input class=​"submit_class" type=​"submit" value=​"Submit">​
```

The question is how could I change the values of my 1000 tags to be, lets say, 30, not 20  and submit all the changes using final submit-tag. 
All I need is a human-like behavior on the page on a big amount of data performed by python script.
I suspect that maybe some special python library would be helpful in this case.
Thanks in advance for any help or pointing directions to look at!

Comment: @David Wolever, I have tried to urllib2.urlopen html page, and than I understood that I dont know what to do next with the whole page and dont know the library which could manipulate(change, edit) tags and submit the form. I think that **alecxe** `s answer would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options to change the input values and submit a form:

- [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)
- [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/)
- [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/)

Note that `Selenium` and `Ghost.py` use a real browser. `Mechanize` is the easiest way to go in your case, just note that it may not work for you if there is a lot of javascript involved in the form initializing or submitting process.

Comment: Not using real browser is a benefit for me. Your links is helpful.